# Rename the file and the name of the class inside in the same time

Tags: vim

For php files, is there any plugin that renames the file and the name of the class inside in the same time?

Comment: Since PHP doesn't have a strong convention for class file naming, what is your convention?  Some use `class.ClassName.php` others use things like `classes/ClassName.php`, others use no convention at all.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks, now im using `classes/ClassName.php`, anyway I thinking that would be even better to change all the occurrencies that there are in the project about that file..

Comment: On what platform? If you have a Unix CLI toolchain available, it may be more easily done than in Vim (this is not to say there isn't some plugin out there - I just don't know of one offhand)